# Last test at cypress is showing all assertions

Tags: node.js, testing, graphql, cypress, assertion

I'm new at using Cypress as automation test framework. Currently I'm Trying to use Cypress to automate tests in a GraphQL based API. I can call the api, get the response without problem, but when I tried to do asserts with "Assert.Equal("response variable", "expected msg")", my asserts only appears at the last describe although all my describes at the Test.js has then, as the example
Two describes with assertions but only the last show then
[image]

Comment: Could you share your code with us? It would help to be able to view the test file you're running

Comment: There is the code i'm talking about

https://ctxt.io/2/AABANaYoFA

Comment: Offtopic: But why would anyone build an API with non-english interface/keys?

Answer (score 0):

The tests are running asynchronously, which makes the testrunner to be faster then the actual return of the results.

Take a look at their async recipies .. `async/await` or at least returning a promise could be your friend:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/unit-testing__application-code/async-methods.js

If you do not like `async/await`, your last test could look like that:

```
it('ConsultaCredenciado por cnpj',function(){
  return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
    var client = require('graphql-client')({
        url: 'apiURL/credenciadosplant/',
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        }
      })

    client.query(
        `query{
            consultarCredenciado(cnpj :"123456456")
            {
              IdCredenciado
              CNPJ
              IdCredenciadoLegado
              Email
            }
          }`,function(req,res){
          if(res.status === 401){
              throw new error('Not Authorized')
          }
      }).then(function(res){
        console.log(res)
        expect(res.data.consultarCredenciado[0].Email).to.equal('aaaaa@aaaaaa.com')
        resolve(true);
    })
  });
});
```